# Moment JS to Carbon conversion

Tags: jquery, laravel, timestamp, momentjs, php-carbon

How can I get the same timestamp from MomentJS to Carbon instance (GMT timezone)?

```
$(document).on('click', '#confirm-reservation .dropdown-menu a', function () {
    $('#insert_text').text($(this).text());
    var href = $(e.relatedTarget).data('href');
    var time = moment().year(startTime.format("Y")).month(startTime.format("M")).date(startTime.format("D"))
            .hour($(this).text().split(':')[0]).minutes($(this).text().split(':')[1]).seconds("0");

    console.log(time);

    $('.btn-ok').attr('href', href + '/' + time.unix());
});
```

I am getting the correct selected value in the console which says GMT+2.

If I assign the 2 hour less value, it still get's parsed wrong.

Here is Laravel controller:

```
public function reserveTo($time, $timeTo)
{
    Reservation::create([
        'reserved_from' => Carbon::createFromTimestamp($time),
        'reserved_to' => Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timeTo),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I can see single parameter passed, how to pass two parameters to the `reserveTo` method?

Comment: First parameter always gets through in the route (href), and if other time is picked, then it gets added to the existing route. So I have `/time/timeTo` passed

Answer (score 0):

did you have checked server time?

Carbon will get server time and Moment will get clients time

normally we should trust just single points of time (from server or client)
if you need 2 points of time just append timezone (UTC +2 blabla.. ) to your timestamp

Comment: any answers to this question?